# What is the right way to do a simple POST in NextJS 13.4 API? (Response, NextAPIResponse, NextResponse) using the new App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13

What is the right way to do a simple POST in NextJS 13.4 in the new App Router?

The previous way of doing POST with using NextAPIRequest, NextAPIResponse, using if (req.method === 'POST') , pulling parameters from the URL via something like this const { id } = request.query;, and throwing error messages with NextAPIResponse seems to be outdated.

The question is relevant for POST, PUT, GET, and DELETE ... each has a little naunce and difference.  For clarity - asking about POST here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated POST api in NextJS 13.4 using the new `app routing` with error messages included.

For clarity of the example, I'll include a call to a `supabase client`; the API you're calling can be different but you can see the error messages and such.

```
// FILE NAME /app/api/tacos/route.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import supabase from '../../supabase/client';

export async function POST(request) {
    try {
       // ! OLD WAY
       // const { id, id, newData } = req.body; // ! OLD WAY
       // const dataOldWay = JSON.parse(request.body); // ! OLD WAY
       const {data} = await request.json();

       const { data: insertedData, error } = await supabase.from("my_table").upsert(data).select();

       if (error) {
          console.log("error catch");
          
          return NextResponse.json({ error: "Internal Server Error" }, { status: 500 });
          // ! THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK - will assume and return a status 200 response
          // return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal Server Error', status: 500 });
       }

       return NextResponse.json({ insertedData });
    } catch {
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Catch Error - Internal Server Error' }, { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

For clarity, in Typescript this function signature would be
`export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {`

Read more on route handlers [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers).

And for completeness, here is a very simple function I used in my client-side app to call this API.

```
// This is being called from a Page in your React app
// 'use client';
// import React from 'react`;
// ... define your other import statements here

const postData = async () => {
   const data = { key1: 'value1', key2: 22222222 };

   try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/saveCalculation", {
         method: "POST",
         body: JSON.stringify({data}),
         headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
         },
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        //console.log("A OKAY");
        console.log("OKAY");
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("postData - data upserted", responseData);
      } else {
         // Handle the error
        //  console.log("NOKAY");

        console.log("NOT OKAY");
         const data = await response.json();
         console.log("postData - data NOT upserted", responseData);
      }
   } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error", error);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log("postData - try/catch - error", responseData);
   }
};
```

Note: You can of course consolidate responseData declaration higher up in code, but I kept it simple, with a smaller scope for readability.